# How do i install another ubuntu 12.04 , while one exists inside Windows 7 through Wubi

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, wubi

I am trying to install one more instance of ubuntu 12.04 on my machine so that i can play around with its drivers. I want the already installed version ( done through wubi on my windows 7) , to be untouched. So overall , my computer currently has 2 operating systems.One being windows 7 , and the other being ubuntu 12.04 installed through wubi. What would be the least invasive way to install another ubuntu 12.04 ? Can i do it using a bootup disk/flash just like i do a normal install, or do it through wubi itself?

PS : i do not want to lose any data. There is a lot of stuff on my Laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! But, you have to create extra partition for the new installation.

Comment: I am assuming that this is just like creating another partition while doing a windows/linux install from boot.I could try that. :) .Thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: or you can just backup your wubi root file and play around, if something goes wrong, just copy the backed up root file, simple...

Comment: Just be careful when creating partitions, make sure that you have enough space first.

Comment: @ Mitch, you are right. I think Sreekanth Narayanaswamy has to be careful with the partitioning, if he's not conversant with the process. It is usually different from the way it is done in Windows. I would advise him to take a peep on how to create multiple partitions in linux with other operating systems :  http://www.howtoplaza.com/create-disk-partitions-ubuntu